# Updated mid-2009 MacBook Pro to Mavericks, now it shuts down while not in use

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, crash

I just updated my mid-2009 Macbook Pro to Mavericks and now it regularly shuts down while it is asleep or closed. I have to restart it and receive a message that it "shut down because of a problem." Does anyone have any insight into what is going on?

Below is the most recent crash report:

```
Process:         gutenprint.5.2 [430]
Path:            /usr/libexec/cups/driver/gutenprint.5.2
Identifier:      gutenprint.5.2
Version:         ???
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  cups-driverd [429]
Responsible:     cupsd [117]
User ID:         26

Date/Time:       2013-11-16 22:55:10.286 +0000
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9 (13A603)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  E6CABB17-89D1-A8A9-DA33-CB8AE24BB654


Crashed Thread:  0

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libgutenprint.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/libexec/cups/driver/gutenprint.5.2
  Reason: image not found

Binary Images:
    0x7fff61ea3000 -     0x7fff61ed6817  dyld (239.3) <D1DFCF3F-0B0C-332A-BCC0-87A851B570FF> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff85b23000 -     0x7fff85b24ff7  libSystem.B.dylib (1197.1.1) <BFC0DC97-46C6-3BE0-9983-54A98734897A> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff87a71000 -     0x7fff87a8dfff  libresolv.9.dylib (54) <11C2C826-F1C6-39C6-B4E8-6E0C41D4FA95> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
    0x7fff88c42000 -     0x7fff88e9aff1  com.apple.security (7.0 - 55471) <233831C5-C457-3AD5-AFE7-E3E2DE6929C9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
    0x7fff89234000 -     0x7fff89325ff9  libiconv.2.dylib (41) <BB44B115-AC32-3877-A0ED-AEC6232A4563> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
    0x7fff8c07c000 -     0x7fff8c0c3ff7  libcups.2.dylib (372) <348EED62-6C20-35D6-8EFB-E80943965100> /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
    0x7fff8d63b000 -     0x7fff8d820ff7  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 855.11) <E22C6A1F-8996-349C-905E-96C3BBE07C2F> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff90124000 -     0x7fff9013dff7  com.apple.Kerberos (3.0 - 1) <F108AFEB-198A-3BAF-BCA5-9DFCE55EFF92> /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos
    0x7fff91be2000 -     0x7fff91c45ff7  com.apple.SystemConfiguration (1.13 - 1.13) <F05F4149-981B-380B-8F50-51CE804BBB89> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
    0x7fff92b7a000 -     0x7fff92b8bff7  libz.1.dylib (53) <42E0C8C6-CA38-3CA4-8619-D24ED5DD492E> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib


System Profile:
Model: MacBookPro5,5, BootROM MBP55.00AC.B03, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.26 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.47f2
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, PCI, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364A53463235363634485A2D3147314631
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364A53463235363634485A2D3147314631
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x8D), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.0f6 12982, 3 services, 15 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: ST9160314ASG, 160.04 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-868
USB Device: iPhone
USB Device: Built-in iSight
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Answer (score 1):

Well that crash report just says that a printer driver is improperly installed and that is causing some issues. However it's not likely crashing your whole computer. The kernel logs are the more likely place to find that info.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How do I access said kernel logs in Mavericks? I can't seem to find them.

Comment: Open Console.app (in the /Applications/Utilities dir) and filter by kernel or choose kernel from the source list of the left bottom area (this list may be hidden by default, if so click the little triangle in a box button in the lower left to show it).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to ask you a seemingly dumb question, but have you unchecked the box under System Preferences -> Security and Privacy -> Advanced -> Log system out after 30 minutes of inactivity?

That fixed it for me.

Ambar

Comment: Note the OP says the computer shuts-down this is not logging out or going to sleep